# Entity Framework Is there a way to Add-Migration for a specific Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 in one of my ASP MVC 5 application.

I am in a situation where I have 10 Entities in my application. For example, The entities are E1,E2,E3,........

At this point if I execute **Add-Migration** then its creating migration for all of these entities. But I want to have a separate migration for the entity **E1** and then I want to keep rest of all entities in another Migration.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: migrations relate to a context.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new DbContext class with one entity in it and make a migration for that context using "Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName yourcontextnamespace" and then Add-migration. 
Then add one more entity to it and make another migration.
Keep doing this until all entities have their separate migrations.

This also works when you are connecting to an existing DB and you want to create a new entity. Make a new context with just that entity and add a migration for that context.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have one entity per migration you can only do this:

1. Add a single entity
2. Add-Migration
3. Go to 1